# Tricky integral on a region in 3D space

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y) = (x+y)^2 $ and let $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be the set enclosed between the lines $x = y $, $x+y = 2$, $x+y= 4$, $x^2 - y^2=4$. I want to find $\int_{\Omega} f $. How can I draw this set ?

Comment: Seems a change of variables $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$ could be useful. Then you're integrating $u^2$ over the region bounded by $v=0$, $u=2$, $u=4$, $uv=4$.

Comment: You have three lines and a hyperbola. You should be able to plot them.